# Sending a Process HANDLE over TCP

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, handle, winsock2

I have created a simple server in C on one system and a client on another. My goals is take a process running on the server, send its process HANDLE to the connecting system, and by using *ReadProcessMemory*, read and interpret specific data values.

I am well aware of the problems that come with data transfer on differing architectures, which is I would like to see if what I am proposing is even feasible before attempting such a difficult task. My questions are as followed:

1. Is a HANDLE simply only a reference to, in my case, the process? Meaning that if I successfully sent the process handle to the client, I wouldn't be able to do anything with it?
2. If the above is true, is there some sort of way that I can take a snapshot or dump the memory of the process, send the dump via TCP (using Winsock of course), and read and sort through the memory on the client. If so, would that piece of data be too large to send.

I would like to stress that the reading of the process' memory must be done by the client system and not the server

Comment: A handle is a machine-local property in the case of a process handle.  Sending to another machine is pointless, it can't do anything with it.

Comment: Agreed. `ReadProcessMemory()` cannot be used across machine boundaries.  **IF** the client and server are on the same machine, then it will work.  As for how to send a `HANDLE`, it is just a pointer, so type-cast it to an `int` (32bit system) or `__int64` (64bit system) and send that, then type-cast it back to `HANDLE` on the other side. Of course, that means the client and server have to be both 32bit or both 64bit processes so the `HANDLE` has proper meaning, otherwise you risk truncating the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`HANDLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#HANDLE) is a value. Its meaning is only useful to the local system and processes. You pass the `HANDLE` as argument to Windows APIs to interact with the corresponding process/window/etc, therefore it's not really useful to remote systems for anything besides identification.
2. Yes, you can take a snapshot of a memory region and send it over socket. In fact, you can send pretty much anything over socket. It's up to you to process the received data and give meaning to it. If you don't, it's just garbage being transferred.

> I would like to stress that the reading of the process' memory must be done by the client system and not the host.

If I understand you correctly, what you call *host* is actually your *server*. The client **cannot read the server's memory directly**. Your final goal can be accomplished though. You'll have to define a communication protocol like the following:

1. [**client**] Request a list of HANDLEs or PIDs (process identifiers);
2. [**server**] Read the request, send the list of PIDs, and wait for more requests;
3. [**client**] Receive the list of PIDs;
4. [**client**] Request a snapshot of a single PID, and wait for it;
5. [**server**] Receive the snapshot request, and interpret it;
6. [**server**] Take the snapshot;
7. [**server**] Send the snapshot to the client, and wait for more requests;
8. [**client**] Receive the snapshot, and process it;
9. [**client**] Do something else?

As for any network communication, special attention must be given to byte order.

Answer (score 1):

The `ReadProcessMemory()` call can only be invoked from a process running on the same machine as the process to which the HANDLE belongs.

The server can pass the HANDLE to what it believes is the remote client, however the actual receiver could be a proxy process that is running on the same machine as the server. The client then instructs the proxy what values it wants read, and the proxy reads them and returns them.

```
Client Machine              Server Machine 
--------------              --------------
+--------+                  +-------+        +--------+
| Client |                  | Proxy |        | Server |
+--------+                  +-------+        +--------+
    |- Get HANDLE ------------->|                |
    |                           |- Get HANDLE -->|
    |                           |<------ HANDLE -|
    |<------------- Got HANDLE -|                |
    |- Read data value x ------>|
    |                           |ReadProcessMemory()
    |<------------- value of x -|
    |- Read data value y ------>|
    |                           |ReadProcessMemory()
    |<------------- value of y -|
```

This is approximately how [`gdbserver`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdbserver) works when you perform remote debugging.